# Formatting floats to a certain precision in python

Tags: python, floating-point, formatting, precision

Firstly sorry if this problem is posted already however i couldn't find it.

I have just started with python and coding in PyCharm.
Doing some exercises and can't understand why my recipe is not being formatted correctly.

As You see in picture I would like to format the outcome(float number) with '.2f' precision . it works with with some numbers but as I input 11 or 45, 99

The amount is not formatted with .2 accuracy. I'm newbie to this but so could You please show me the light or at least point where to find the candle? (solution)

[image: cookie_problem]

Comment: Code in question body _only_, no pictures...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve then click `edit` to edit your question so that we may help.  Specifically, you need to include all relevant information *within the body of the question* so that if the link disappears, the question will still be valid and useful. It also becomes much easier for us, so you're more likely to get the help you need!  Other useful links are: what kinds of questions can I ask https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, and How to ask: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. All the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call format after you have done the multiplication. In your code you only format the sugar, butter etc. values, but you should format the sugar_calcul etc. values for it to show properly

```
print('For', cookies, 'You would need the following:')
print(format(sugar_calcul, '.2f'),': cups of sugar')
print(format(butter_calcul, '.2f'), ': cups of butter')
print(format(flour_calcul, '.2f'), ': cups of flour')
print('Enjoy Your cookies !')
```